# Reading and writing to files in the same iteration

Tags: python, file, python-2.6

Suppose I have a list of files, and I want to iterate over it, for each one reading its content, sending the content to a function `processContent()`, and writing the whole thing back into the file. Would the following code be an appropriate way to do it?

```
for curfile in files:
    with open(curfile, 'r+') as infile
        content = infile.read()
        processed_content = processContent(content)
        infile.write(processed_content)
```

In other words, reading and writing in the same iteration.

Comment: I believe you would want `infile.seek(0)` prior to writing ... really you should just use 2 handles ...

Comment: I prefer working with a temp file and then renaming it back to the original file name.

Comment: @StevenRumbalski I see what you're saying, but will it cause a problem since I'm also iterating over files?

Comment: @Mika H:  I see no issue, could you expand on what problem you see with the approach.

Comment: Why would it?  You can just copy back the temp file as part of the iteration.

Comment: @StevenRumbalski Ah, there should be no issue. I was just confused on my own.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
for curfile in files:
    with open(curfile, 'r+') as infile:
        content = infile.read()
        processed_content = processContent(content)
        infile.truncate(0)   # truncate the file to 0 bytes
        infile.seek(0)       # move the pointer to the start of the file
        infile.write(processed_content)
```

Or use a temporary file to write the new content and then rename it back to the original file:

```
import os
for curfile in files:
    with open(curfile) as infile:
        with open("temp_file", 'w') as outfile:
            content = infile.read()
            processed_content = processContent(content)
            outfile.write(processed_content)
    os.remove(curfile) # For windows only
    os.rename("temp_file", curfile)
```

If you want to process one line at once then try [`fileinput`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/fileinput.html) module

Comment: This works, but it makes me uncomfortable.  Something about truncating and seeking feels a little too low level.

Comment: @F3AR3DLEGEND The question is tagged with py2.6

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary Ah, didn't see that.

Comment: Docs say that `os.rename` will throw `OSError` on Windows if the file exists.

Comment: @StevenRumbalski So doing `os.remove(curfile)` before renaming?